# Phantom JS Button Click and HTTP Auth

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I'm doing some experiementation with PhantomJS to see if I want to use it for automated testing of a webapp I'm developing. I'm very new to PhantomJS, so I'm not sure what I'm doing entirely. I have searched around for this, but haven't seen anything about it.

However, my question is, how would you open a webpage, submit a form, and then perform HTTP authentication against the page that is redirected from the form?

My website has a form with a button that needs to be clicked on before it prompts for HTTP authentication.

The code I have right now is the following:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://...../';
page.open(url, function(status) {
  console.log('page has been loaded: ' + url);
  page.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementByClassName('ctabutton').click();
  });
console.log('status: ' + status);
phantom.exit();
```

I'm assuming that I need to somehow get the URL of the page that is requiring the HTTP auth from the clicking of the button/submission of the form, and then open that page, and perform whatever basic http auth process phantomJS supports.

Note: This has been marked as a duplicate to another question, but it is not the same. I'm not asking about the buggy details of phantomjs and how it handles http authentication, I'm asking how do you use http authentication in phantomjs when the authentication prompt is the result of clicking a button that is part of a form. I guess there's no way to contest a 'duplicate' label on your question.

Comment: So, what exactly do you have trouble with? Is it waiting for the page load after you click something? Also, HTTP-Authentication is a pretty broad term that doesn't mean anything. What authentication type are you actually talking about?

Comment: So, in my code above, I'm clicking the button. Do I need the URL to the page that requires the authentication? If so, how do I get it? Also, how do I even perform the authentication? I don't know how else to describe it, other than Basic HTTP Authentication. An Image of the authentication box is at the following url: http://imgur.com/a/n0NAS. Maybe you can tell me what it is.